# A bag contains $N$ white balls and $M$ black balls, $3$ balls are chosen at random what is the probability

Tags: probability

A bag contains $N$ white balls and $M$ black balls, $3$ balls are chosen at random. What is the probability that at least a pair of chosen balls are white or black?

To the best of my knowledge, it is a case of not mutually exclusive $A$ or $B$, because they are being drawn from the same bag.

So probability of $P(A \text{ or } B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \text{ and } B)$.

But I don't know whether it is right or not. Need some help!

Comment: What are the other possibilities?

Comment: have you tried something that you might want to tell us  and describe in the question to show us your effort?

Comment: nothing else is given, just this. I want to know the formula to calculate this. Thanks in advance @DJohnM

Comment: @James I'm sorry for not adding it before.

Comment: If $3$ balls are chosen then it cannot be that at least 2 are white **and** 2 are black. So P(A and B)=0.

Comment: @drhab out of 3 balls, a pair is white or a pair is black.

Comment: Exactly, so the probability is $1$.

Comment: if $3$ balls are there and each of them is white or black then of course there is a pair with the same color.

Comment: why op edited the question first it was at least 2 balls are white or  2 balls are black

Comment: James, that is what the current question is asking.  "at least a pair of chosen balls are white or black?" is the same as, "at least 2 balls are white or two balls are black."

Comment: Naman: This is true assuming  a minimum of three balls exist in the bag such that all three are white, all three are black, two are white and one is black, one is white and two are black.  You'll find that even as M, N increase, you'll find you'll always have a pair of the same color.

Answer (score 0):

In this type of questions, you have to always count the possibilities to calculate the probability

here you want at least  2 white balls while choosing three balls

thus possibilities are  $$I)2 W \space \space 1 B $$
$$II)  3 W $$

also in the question, it is mentioned that 2 balls are black thus 
the  possibility is $$ i) 2 B \space 1 W $$
$$ ii) 3 B $$
now calculate the probabality $$P=\frac{ \binom {N}{2}*\binom{M}{1}+\binom{N}{3}+\binom{M}{2}\binom{N}{1}+\binom{M}{3}}{\binom{N+M}{3}}$$

Comment: Thanks it helped!

Comment: James: Please refrain from showing how desparate you are for rep.  Never ask a user to accept "your" answer mere minutes after the post was submitted.  The asker is wise to wait for other answers, or better yet, the asker would be wise to improve their question, asked already today.

Answer (score 0):

When you see "at least" or "either"in a probability question, it often means that the complement or reverse probability is a better calculation.  Especially here!

So,

***When drawing three balls from a collection of white balls and black balls, what is the probability that each of the three is a different color?***